# Error in deploying project with eclipse and tomcat

Tags: eclipse, maven, tomcat

I am not sure what is going on, but I am unable to deploy my project using eclipse... It worked a few days ago, and now I keep getting the same errors

Any help will be greatly appreciated... This is what I get:

```
SEVERE: Error configuring application listener of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1680)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1526)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4149)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4705)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:799)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:779)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:601)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:675)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptors(HostConfig.java:601)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:502)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1317)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:324)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:142)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1065)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:840)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:463)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:525)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:754)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
Sep 13, 2013 2:04:06 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Skipped installing application listeners due to previous error(s)
Sep 13, 2013 2:04:06 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SEVERE: Error listenerStart
Sep 13, 2013 2:04:06 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SEVERE: Context [/activate] startup failed due to previous errors
Sep 13, 2013 2:04:06 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFO: Deploying configuration descriptor host-manager.xml
Sep 13, 2013 2:04:07 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFO: Deploying configuration descriptor manager.xml
Sep 13, 2013 2:04:07 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory docs
Sep 13, 2013 2:04:07 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory examples
Sep 13, 2013 2:04:07 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: ContextListener: contextInitialized()
Sep 13, 2013 2:04:07 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: SessionListener: contextInitialized()
Sep 13, 2013 2:04:07 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory ROOT
Sep 13, 2013 2:04:07 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol start
INFO: Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
Sep 13, 2013 2:04:07 PM org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket init
INFO: JK: ajp13 listening on /0.0.0.0:8009
Sep 13, 2013 2:04:07 PM org.apache.jk.server.JkMain start
INFO: Jk running ID=0 time=0/31  config=null
Sep 13, 2013 2:04:07 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 935 ms
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ContextLoaderListener`is part of spring-web, so at first this should be visible under "Maven Dependencies" of your web project (and of course your web project has to be a dynamic web project with maven nature).

With eclipse "Kepler" we had the issue that after doing a "Maven->Update Project" the dependency resolution for the server start was lost.

Check with right-click on web project->Properties->Deployment Assembly. Maven Dependencies should be in the source column with WEB-INF/lib as target. Otherwise you have to add it with "Add..->Java Build Path Entries -> Maven Dependencies".